# How do I let a boat drift for a few seconds after the movement key is unpressed

Tags: c#, monogame

So I'm trying to make a 2D game in which the player controls a boat from overhead. I have it so the boat rotates when the "A" and "D" keys are pressed, and moves forward/backwards when the "W" and "S" keys are pressed. I'd like to make the boat drift at decreasing speed for a few seconds after the forward and backwards keys are released, but I'm not sure how to do this. Here is my code for the Ship class. I'm thinking about using a "While" loop somehow but I'm not quite sure how. I also would like the bow of the boat to continually update to be moving towards the rotation created.

I have an enum in the main method, which is where "Dir" comes from.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


//width = 62 pixels
//height = 179 pixels

namespace my_first_game
{
class Ship
{

    private Vector2 position = new Vector2(300, 300);
    private int radius = 50;
    private bool ismoving = false;
    private Dir direction = Dir.down;
    private int health = 3;
    private float speed = 200;
    public float angle = 0;
    public double turntime = .01d;
    private float drifting = 0;
    private bool isdrifting = false;

    Vector2 Boat_Tip = new Vector2(0, 0);



   // Constructor for the ship class
   public Ship(int shiphealth)
    {
        shiphealth = health;
    }

    /* public float Get_angle
     {
         get { return angle; }

     }
     */

    //get and set health
    public int Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set { value = health; }
    }

    // get the ship's position
    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get{ return position; }
    }

    //update loop for the ship's state
    public void update_ship(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState kstate = Keyboard.GetState();
        float dt = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        Boat_Tip.X = position.X;
        Boat_Tip.Y = position.Y;

        //if keys are pressed, the ship moves until the keys are unpressed

        if (kstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            direction = Dir.up;
            ismoving = true;
            isdrifting = true;
        }
        if (kstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            direction = Dir.left;
            ismoving = true;
        }
        if (kstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            direction = Dir.right;
            ismoving = true;
        }
        if (kstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            direction = Dir.down;
            ismoving = true;
        }


        //"ismoving" is used as a flag to move the ship if keys are held
        //angle also rotates the boat when "A" and "D" are pressed
        if (ismoving) {

            switch (direction) {
                case Dir.up:
                    position.Y -= speed * dt;
                    ismoving = false;
                    break;
                case Dir.down:

                    position.Y += speed * dt;
                    ismoving = false;
                    break;
                case Dir.left:
                    position.X -= speed *(float)turntime * dt;
                    angle -= (float).01;
                    ismoving = false;
                    break;
                case Dir.right:
                    position.X += speed *(float)turntime * dt;
                    angle += (float).01;
                    ismoving = false;
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Not sure if this helps, but here is my ship draw method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(ship_sprite, ship.Position, ship_rectangle, Color.White, 
ship.angle, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
```

Comment: Instead of setting speed when a key is pressed, give the boat some "momentum".  Each frame, if a key is held down, add some value to a momentum variable.  After that, move the boat's position by the momentum value, then subtract a "friction" value from the momentum so that it gradually drops to 0.  You will need to experament a bit to find the best values for your game that strike a balance between acceleration, max speed, and friction.

Comment: @BradleyUffner that makes sense. The only issue I’m having is how to increase momentum by each frame. For example, would doing “momentum++” increase the momentum by 1 each frame? I’m pretty new to monogamy and programming in general.

Comment: That could work, but it's probably too slow.  Your class should probably have an acceleration property that you use for that number. That way you can boost it with something like powerups.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and simple solution would be to have a current_speed and a target_speed. Your keypresses just set the target_speed and then in update you lerp the current_speed to the target_speed

```
float cur_speed;
float trg_speed;

void Update()
{
    if( keypressed) trg_speed = 200f;
    else trg_speed = 0f;

    cur_speed = lerp(cur_speed,trg_speed,0.2f);

    // do your other movement here depending on cur_speed
}
```

something like that - if the travelled distance is important to be framerate independent you have to take the elapsed time into account - maybe use a physics engine to do it for you